# How to load the activity of the application on android using scheme

Tags: android, xamarin, deep-linking

I tried to load an apk file with

> ./adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "mytest://myFunApp" com.companyname.oauthnativeflow
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mytest://myFunApp pkg=com.companyname.oauthnativeflow }

and the setting on xamarin android activity

```
[Activity(Label = "CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    DataScheme = "mytest",
    DataHost = "myFunApp",
    DataPathPrefix = "/",
    AutoVerify = true)
]
//[IntentFilter(
//  new[] { Intent.ActionView },
//  Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
//  DataSchemes = new[] { "com.googleusercontent.apps.863494635082-a617p00qkuafejrf3k7hq8s346l0u36h" },
//  DataPath = "/oauth2redirect")]
public class CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
```

I have checked the package name is correct but could not load the activity

Comment: What is the result in `logcat`?

Comment: What i get is Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mytest://myFunApp } from the command

Comment: try to add `android:export="true"`